# Error: Could not find CSR for: domain when using puppet cert sign

Tags: ssl, debian, apache2, puppet

I'm trying to sign my node (for a puppetmaster) only whatever I do I'm getting the error below:

```
Error: Could not find CSR for: [domain name]
```

The node is indeed listed under  puppet cert list —all

Comment: If you can list the cert, but you cannot sign it, then perhaps it has already been signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to remove the cert from the puppet directory(generally located in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl`) and re-issue it.

From my experiences, this always works. The [Puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#step-3-clear-and-regenerate-certs-for-puppet-agents) covers this rather well.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced same problem, but resolved by giving complete hostname.
Run this first :-
`puppet cert list`
`output :-`
`"hostname.domainname.com" (SHA256) 2D:A2:4F...B6:9C`
After that get the hostname from above output, and give it below :-
`puppet cert sign hostname.domainname.com`