# puppet agent broke after manual run

Tags: ssl, puppet, manifest

I had to 2 agent nodes with one master configuration. Certificates were signed normally. I ran the manifest on the master `puppet apply site.pp`, and everything went fine. However, no agents executed the manifest so I ran on one of them :

`sudo puppet agent -t` with the output `Notice: Skipping run of Puppet configuration client; administratively disabled (Reason: 'Disabled by default on new or unconfigured old installations');
Use 'puppet agent --enable' to re-enable.`

So that I ran, `sudo puppet agent --enable` and then again `sudo puppet agent -t --debug`. And here's the output

`Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=cluster-b665-m.c.some_project-182409.internal]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Debug: Creating new connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Debug: Starting connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=cluster-b665-m.c.some_project-182409.internal]
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Debug: Creating new connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Debug: Starting connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal/pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=cluster-b665-m.c.some_project-182409.internal]
Wrapped exception:
...
Wrapped exception:
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=cluster-b665-m.c.some_project-182409.internal]
Debug: Finishing transaction 29645260
Debug: Loading external facts from /var/lib/puppet/facts.d
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: catalog supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml dot raw
Debug: Creating new connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Debug: Starting connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=cluster-b665-m.c.some_project-182409.internal]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Debug: Executing '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post'
Debug: Creating new connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Debug: Starting connection for https://cluster-b665-m.europe-west1-b.c.some_project-182409.internal:8140
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=cluster-b665-m.c.some_project-182409.internal]`

How can I deal with that ?

Comment: Did your agents ever successfully perform catalog requests?  I.e., before you ran your `puppet apply` on the master?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things this could be.  Is it listening on the appropriate port to allow this server to issue an SSL to your agent, or blocking it in some other way(firewall/iptables/etc.)?

These are all just guesses, but it looks like your agent is not connecting to the master or is having an issue with the SSL cert. You may need to remove the ssl from the directory and re-issue/re-sign it.  I would start by making sure that the agent is able to connect to an active master ,and by running a 'puppet cert list --all' and see if there is any issues with that agent, or if the agent has a certificate on the master at all.

For removing and re-issuing a certificate manually, you can view my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100979/error-could-not-find-csr-for-domain-when-using-puppet-cert-sign/48426865#48426865)